# errors in program ClockType.h, testClockType.cpp, and ClockTypeImp.cpp

Tags: c++

Still have 7 errors:

1. clockTypeImp.cpp:48: error: prototype for ‘void ClockType::getTime(int&, int&, int&) const’ does not match any in class ‘ClockType’
2. clockType.h:35: error: candidate is: void ClockType::getTime(int&, int&, int&)
3. clockTypeImp.cpp:98: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
4. clockTypeImp.cpp:109: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘clockType’ with no type
5. clockTypeImp.cpp:109: error: no ‘int ClockType::clockType()’ member function declared in class ‘ClockType’
6. clockTypeImp.cpp:118: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘clockType’ with no type
7. clockTypeImp.cpp:118: error: no ‘int ClockType::clockType(int, int, int)’ member function declared in class ‘ClockType’

testClockType.cpp

## include

## include "clockType.h"

using namespace std;

```
int main() 
{
    
    int cellHours;
    int cellMinutes;
    int cellSeconds;
    int computerHours;
    int computerMinutes;
    int computerSeconds;
    
    cout << "Please tell me the hour on your cell phone: ";
    cin >> cellHours;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the minute on your cell phone: ";
    cin >> cellMinutes;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the second on your cell phone: ";
    cin >> cellSeconds;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the hour on your computer: ";
    cin >> computerHours;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the minute on your computer: ";
    cin >> computerMinutes;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the second on your computer: ";
    cin >> computerSeconds;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Your cell phone time is: " << endl; 
    ClockType cellPhoneClock; 
    cellPhoneClock.setTime(cellHours, cellMinutes, cellSeconds); 
    cellPhoneClock.printTime();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Your computer time is: " << endl; 
    ClockType myComputerClock;
    myComputerClock.setTime(computerHours, computerMinutes, computerSeconds);
    myComputerClock.printTime();
    cout << endl;
    
    if(!cellPhoneClock.equalTime(myComputerClock))
    {
       cout << "Both clocks do not have equal times" << endl;
       cout << "Setting myComputerClock to the cellPhoneClock time" << endl;
       int hours, minutes, seconds;
       cellPhoneClock.getTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
       myComputerClock.getTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "Both clocks have equal times" << endl;
   }
   cout << endl << "Final cell phone time is: ";
   cellPhoneClock.printTime();
   cout << endl << "Final computer time is: ";
   cellPhoneClock.printTime();
   cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

clockTypeImp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clockType.h"

class ClockType; 

void ClockType::setTime (int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    if ( 0 <= hours && hours < 24 )
        hr = hours; //added int to initialize
    else
        hr = 0;
    
    if ( 0 <= minutes && minutes < 60 )
        min = minutes; //added int to initialize
    else
        min = 0;
    
    if ( 0 <= seconds && seconds < 60 )
        sec = seconds; //added int to initialize
    else
        sec = 0;
}

void ClockType::getTime (int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds) const
//error: prototype for ‘void ClockType::getTime(int&, int&, int&) const’ does not match any in class ‘ClockType’
{
    hours = hr;
    minutes = min;
    seconds = sec;
}

void ClockType::printTime() const
{
    if (hr < 10)
        cout << "0";
    cout << hr << ":";
    
    if (min < 10)
        cout << "0";
    cout << min << ":";
    
    if (sec < 10)
        cout << "0";
    cout << sec << ":";
}

void ClockType::incrementHours()
{
    hr++;
    if (hr > 23)
        hr = 0;
}

void ClockType::incrementMinutes()
{
    min++;
    if (min > 59)
    {
        min = 0;
        incrementHours(); //increment hours
    }
}

void ClockType::incrementSeconds()
{
    sec++;
    if (sec > 59)
    {
        sec = 0;
        incrementMinutes(); //increment minutes
    }
}

ClockType::equalTime (clockType& myComputerClock) const
//clockTypeImp.cpp:98: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
{
    return (hr == myComputerClock.hr
            && min == myComputerClock.min
            && sec == myComputerClock.sec);
}

ClockType::clockType()
//error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘clockType’ with no type
//error: no ‘int ClockType::clockType()’ member function declared in class ‘ClockType'
{
    hr = 0;
    min = 0;
    sec = 0;
}

ClockType::clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
//error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘clockType’ with no type
//error: no ‘int ClockType::clockType(int, int, int)’ member function declared in class ‘ClockType’
{
    setTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

clockType.h

```
#ifndef CLOCKTYPE_H
#define CLOCKTYPE_H

using namespace std;

class ClockType
{
    public:
        void setTime (int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
        void getTime (int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds); //error: candidate is: void ClockType::getTime(int&, int&, int&)
        void printTime() const;
        void incrementSeconds();
        void incrementMinutes();
        void incrementHours();
        bool equalTime(ClockType& otherClock) const; 
        ClockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
        ClockType();
        
    private:
        int hr;
        int min;
        int sec;
};
#endif
```

Comment: This has far more errors than the one you're looking at. Add back the **smallest** amount of context that results in code that will produce the error message, and include the actual text of the error message.

Comment: I have added all of my code and all errors that I have are comments beside the line. there are a total of 25 errors

Comment: Please don't program by random syntax guessing.

Comment: Down to 20 errors and I am not guessing I just have not been doing this set up very long and am still learning

Comment: @JessicaDuncan pro tip: providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps a lot in getting more users' attention :)

Comment: Again: provide the **smallest** amount of context that will produce the error message. That's an important part of learning how to decipher error messages.

Comment: 19 errors left.

Comment: Updated 7 errors left and they are mostly connected to one another.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the my corrected code that does work.

testClockType.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clockType.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    int cellHours;
    int cellMinutes;
    int cellSeconds;
    int computerHours;
    int computerMinutes;
    int computerSeconds;

    cout << "Please tell me the hour on your cell phone: ";
    cin >> cellHours;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the minute on your cell phone: ";
    cin >> cellMinutes;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the second on your cell phone: ";
    cin >> cellSeconds;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the hour on your computer: ";
    cin >> computerHours;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the minute on your computer: ";
    cin >> computerMinutes;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please tell me the second on your computer: ";
    cin >> computerSeconds;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "=================================================" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Your cell phone time is: " << endl; 
    ClockType cellPhoneClock; 
    cellPhoneClock.setTime(cellHours, cellMinutes, cellSeconds); 
    cellPhoneClock.printTime();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Your computer time is: " << endl; 
    ClockType myComputerClock;
    myComputerClock.setTime(computerHours, computerMinutes, computerSeconds);
    myComputerClock.printTime();
    cout << endl;

    if(!cellPhoneClock.equalTime(myComputerClock))
    {
       cout << "Both clocks do not have equal times" << endl;
       cout << "Setting Computer clock to the cell Phone Clock time" << endl;
       int hours, minutes, seconds;
       cellPhoneClock.getTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
       myComputerClock.getTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "Both clocks have equal times" << endl;
   }
   cout << endl << "Final cell phone time is: ";
   cellPhoneClock.printTime();
   cout << endl << "Final computer time is: ";
   cellPhoneClock.printTime();
   cout << endl;
    //cout << "===================================================" << endl;
    //cout << endl;
    //cout << "Computer needs to be set 1 Hour, 5 minutes, and  23 seconds ahead of cell phone:" <<endl;


return 0;
}
```

clockTypeImp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clockType.h"

class ClockType; 

void ClockType::setTime (int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    if ( 0 <= hours && hours < 24 )
        hr = hours; //added int to initialize
    else
        hr = 0;

    if ( 0 <= minutes && minutes < 60 )
        min = minutes; //added int to initialize
    else
        min = 0;

    if ( 0 <= seconds && seconds < 60 )
        sec = seconds; //added int to initialize
    else
        sec = 0;
}

void ClockType::getTime (int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds) const
{
    hours = hr;
    minutes = min;
    seconds = sec;
}

void ClockType::printTime() const
{
    if (hr < 10)
        cout << "0";
    cout << hr << ":";

    if (min < 10)
        cout << "0";
    cout << min << ":";

    if (sec < 10)
        cout << "0";
    cout << sec << ":";
}

void ClockType::incrementHours()
{
    hr++;
    if (hr > 23)
        hr = 0;
}

void ClockType::incrementMinutes()
{
    min++;
    if (min > 59)
    {
        min = 0;
        incrementHours(); //increment hours
    }
}

void ClockType::incrementSeconds()
{
    sec++;
    if (sec > 59)
    {
        sec = 0;
        incrementMinutes(); //increment minutes
    }
}

bool ClockType::equalTime (ClockType& myComputerClock)const
{
    return (hr == myComputerClock.hr
            && min == myComputerClock.min
            && sec == myComputerClock.sec);
}

//ClockType::clockType()
//error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘clockType’ with no type
//error: no ‘int ClockType::clockType()’ member function declared in class ‘ClockType'
//{
//  hr = 0;
//  min = 0;
//  sec = 0;
//}

void ClockType::clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
//error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘clockType’ with no type
//error: no ‘int ClockType::clockType(int, int, int)’ member function declared in class ‘ClockType’
{
    setTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

and clockType.h

```
#ifndef CLOCKTYPE_H
#define CLOCKTYPE_H

using namespace std;

class ClockType
{
    public:
        void setTime (int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
        void getTime (int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds) const; 
        void printTime() const;
        void incrementSeconds();
        void incrementMinutes();
        void incrementHours();
        bool equalTime(ClockType& myComputerClock) const; 
        void clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
        void clockType();
        //void newTime (

    private:
        int hr;
        int min;
        int sec;
};
#endif
```